# Combine data into 1 worksheet in Excel via Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a bunch of worksheets in single excel file in the same format. I need to take just one column out of each table and to combine those data in new worksheet and new excel file.

[image: Example of goal]

I have struggled to find solution for my question. But still I have not reached any results.

I will appreciate any help or link to helpful materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pd.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and iterate over each sheet in the workbook.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel( YOUR_FILE, sheet_name=None )
ouput_dict = dict()
for i,sheet in enumerate( data.keys() ):
    temp_df = data[sheet]
    new_col_name = col + str(i)
    output_dict[ new_col_name ] = temp_df[ col ]
final_df = pd.DataFrame( data=output_dict )
```

Inside the `for` loop, `temp_df` will be a pandas [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) based on that individual sheet. In this example you could name the column `new_col_name`, taking the column `col` from that sheet. In your example, `col` would be "Open".

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still experience some problems. I have an issue with this code - `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sheet_names'`. And the same for data.parse. Do you know how to deal with this? Also I am quite new in Python so detailed explanation will be a plus))))

Comment: Fixed the code in the answer to correctly treat 'data' as a dictionary

Comment: somewhat broadly, it's _much_ (orders of magnitude) more efficient to use the pandas/numpy methods rather than creating intermediate python objects, though it may not matter for this case! (especially where readability/understandability is critical and there's probably not a huge number of rows or some webclient waiting for completion)